# Does CDbcommand method queryAll() in yii return indexed entries only?

Tags: yii

I am trying to retrieve data from a simple mySql table `tbl_u_type` which has just two columns, 'tid' and 'type'.

I want to use a direct SQL query instead of the Model logic. I used:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$userArray = $command->select('type')->from('tbl_u_type')->queryAll();
return $userArray;
```

But in the dropdown list it automatically shows an index number along with the required entry. Is there any way I can avoid the index number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an array of data usable in a dropdown, use the [CHtml::listData()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) method. If I understand the question right, this should get you going. Something like this:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$userArray = $command->select('tid, type')->from('tbl_u_type')->queryAll();
echo CHtml::dropdownlist('my_dropdown','',CHtml::listData($userArray,'tid','type'));
```

You can also do this with the Model if you have one set up for the `tbl_u_type` table:

```
$users = UType::model()->findall();
echo CHtml::dropdownlist('my_dropdown','',CHtml::listData($users ,'tid','type'));
```

I hope that gets you on the right track. I didn't test my code here, as usual, so watch out for that. ;) Good luck!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Feel free to upvote my answer if it was helpful. :)

Comment: Hey Evan,how u doin man, listen i need a bit of help in understandin the model usage logic b/w seperate classes..cn u kindly suggest some good sources for in depth understandin of yii?

Comment: The best resources I have found is the Ultimate Guide (read the whole thing!) and spending time in the Yii forums. Also, stepping through a Yii page request with a debugger (XDebug?) will help a LOT with understanding what goes on with Yii. Good luck!