# Yii - Foreign key - Access Data

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I' m just getting into Yii and am finding it a little confusing (at least compared to Cake or CI).  Here's a couple things I'm wondering about:

1) If I have an 'add station' form (using a Station model).  In the form, there will be a drop down list of 'Companies' (from Company Model).  Station belongsTo Company (Station has a foreign key of company_id).

How do I go about generating the drop down list?  Should the Php code used to pull the data be stored in the model, or should it just be a line in the form?

2) I also have the following database tables:

```
station
- id
- location_id

location
- id
- state_id
- city_id

state
- id
- state

city
- id
- city
```

For right now, in the same form as above, I wanted to have a 'Location' field, and then 2 drop downs for city and state.  Whatever the user chooses, would then be stored in the location table as foreign key pairs.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Yeah, this should probably be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Look at my answer to this question for tips about the downdown (the key is CHtml::listData):

[Does CDbcommand method queryAll() in yii return indexed entries only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968285/does-cdbcommand-method-queryall-in-yii-return-indexed-entries-only/4972352#4972352)

2) Is `location` just a relation table between `state` and `city`? Then just do a MANY_MANY [relation()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) in your City and State models. The [AdvancedAR](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cadvancedarbehavior/) extension makes life a little easier for managing MANY_MANY releationships.

Otherwise, just set up a Model for each of your tables, and add the appropriate [relations()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) between them. Then in your form post action, create a new Location and set the `state_id` and `city_id`, and save() it.

Comment: didn't know about the first option, will check that out.  In terms of the 2nd option, I feel like I'm missing something.  To even access the list of states and cities from my initial 'station' form, how would I do that?  They are 2 steps away: as in, Station would need to access Location, which would then need to access the list of States from the State model.  Whats the best way to do that from the form?

Comment: I would just store the state_id and city_id right in the station table, instead of having that extra location table. It would still be easy to query a list of all stations at the same location if you did that, and it would simplify your whole "location" table issue I think. I don't know what you trying to accomplish though, so I'm probably way off.

Comment: maybe you're right.  Honestly, Im just learning Yii by porting an old app I had built.  I was just trying to normalize as much as possible, and I figured it'd be a good way to try and see how easy that sort of thing is in Yii

Comment: Also, just to clarify, in Cake you can just put something in the controller action like $states = States::findAll() sort of thing, and then access that in the view for use in a dropdown.  i suppose im looking to do something like that

Comment: Like this? echo CHtml::dropdownlist('choose_state','',CHtml::listData(State::model()->findall(),'id','state'));